# What is the best book for learning object oriented javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a pro when it comes to HTML/CSS, and can use jQuery pretty well to move things around on my sites, but I need a good book for a NON PROGRAMMING person to learn OO JS. I just can't grasp it. I need a good book for learning! Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good JavaScript Books?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books)

Comment: Duplicate, there are a lot of questions in stackoverflow related to this.

Answer (score 7):

If you are completely new to programming and need to learn JavaScript from the ground up, have a go at the freely available [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html).

[Object-oriented Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html) chapter from Eloquent JavaScript is a good read. I also strongly recommend reading chapters 3-5 from [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) to understand JavaScript Objects, Functions, Inheritance. The best I have read on the topic till now.

Comment: I read Eloquent Javascript and it was amazing. It will definitely guide one through horrible incidents he might be in exposure of inside JS world

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend O'Reilly book [JavaScript Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596806767) by Stoyan Stefanov.

Answer (score 3):

"JavaScript: The Definite Guide" by David Flanagan is a fine one containing comprehensive information of all aspects of JS.

If you want to master JavaScript, I recommend that you Google Mr. Douglas Crockford. Both his website, and like dheerosaur suggested, his book "JavaScript: The Good Parts". The book offers insight of JavaScript including its OO aspect.